# Attempting to make an interesting puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, geometry

[image]

Hmmm, what could it mean?
(it's pretty easy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RGB code for the circled color in MS Paint is:

> 128, 128, 64

If we...

> Replace the variable a, b, c (indicated by RGB-colored lines in the quadratic formula) with the corresponding value we get: x = −0.5+0.5i & x=−0.5−0.5i?

I don't know if I'm missing something, haha.

Comment: sorry I should have made it more clear what the answer was